# Inner product question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, linear-algebra

Why is it valid to write that:

$$\langle\alpha|a^{\dagger}\alpha\rangle=\langle a\alpha|\alpha\rangle$$

where $\alpha$ is the lowering operator, $\alpha^{\dagger}$ is the raising operator, and $a\in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: This question seems confused - $\alpha$ is a vector in the Hilbert space, while $a$ and $a^\dagger$ are the lowering and raising operators, respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The raising operator $a^\dagger$ is the adjoint of the lowering operator $a$. This means$^\ddagger$ that for any two vectors $x$ and $y$,
$$\langle x,ay\rangle = \langle a^\dagger x,y\rangle$$
We therefore may write
$$\langle x,a^\dagger y\rangle = \overline{\langle a^\dagger y,x\rangle} = \overline{\langle y,a x\rangle} = \langle ax,y\rangle$$
where the line denotes complex conjugation. In other words, $(a^\dagger)^\dagger = a$, so we are justified in writing $\langle x,ay\rangle = \langle a^\dagger x,y\rangle$ and $\langle x,a^\dagger y\rangle = \langle a x,y\rangle$ for any vectors $x$ and $y$.  Setting $x=y=\alpha$ yields the result in the OP.

---

$^\ddagger$In fact this is not true, because $a$ and $a^\dagger$ are unbounded operators which cannot act on the entirety of the Hilbert space. As a result, there are subtle domain issues which make the proof that $(a^\dagger)^\dagger = a$ significantly less trivial.  Nevertheless, this (non-trivial) fact is ultimately true, and such domain issues are often (wrongly IMO) categorized as mathematical technicalities beyond the interest of your average physicist.